# How should I speed up Inserts in a large table

Tags: mysql, insert

### Scenario

I have an hourly cron that inserts roughly 25k entries into a table that's about 7 million rows. My Primary Key is a composite of 5 different fields. I did this so that I wouldn't have to search the table for duplicates prior to insert, assuming the dupes would just fall to the floor on insert. Due to PHP memory issues I was seeing while reading these 25k entries in (downloading multiple json files from a url and constructing insert queries), I break the entries into 2k chunks and insert them at once via `INSERT INTO blah (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`. Lastly I should probably mention I'm on DreamHost so I doubt my server/db setup is all that great. Oh and the db is MyIsam(default).

### Problem

Each 2k chunk insert is taking roughly 20-30 seconds(resulting in about a 10 minute total script time including 2 minutes for downloading 6k json files) and while this is happening, user selects from that table appear to be getting blocked/delayed making the website unresponsive for users. My guess would be that the slowdown is coming from the insert trying to index the 5 field PK into a table of 7 million.

### What I'm considering

I originally thought enabling concurrent insert/selects would help the unresponsive site, but as far as I can tell, my table is already MyIsam and I have concurrent inserts enabled.
I read that `LOAD DATA INFILE` is a lot faster so I was thinking of maybe inserting all my values into an empty temp table that will be mostly collision free(besides dupes from the current hour), exporting those w/ `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` and then using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but i don't know if the overhead of inserting and writing negates the speed benefit. Also the guides I've read talk about further optimizing by disabling my indexes prior to insert, but i think that would break my method of avoiding duplicates on insert...

It's probably obvious that I'm a bit clueless here, I know just enough to get myself really confused on what to do next. Any advice on how to speed up the inserts or just to make selects still responsive while these inserts are occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use another table for inserting. When process is finished copy them to your main table.

Comment: Batu Zet is right I think, when cron starts create a copy of your main  table and use it for inserts, when done rename the tables

Comment: This worked great, thanks! It added about 5 minutes to copy the 7 million values, but that's ok for the time being since it's not impacting the user anymore.